# How to ensure only after scrolling the remaining list tiles are rendered via listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination, adapter

I want to ensure that at first only 2 list tiles are rendered. Then only after user scrolls, a progress indicator followed by the remaining list tiles (all list tiles are from API response) should be rendered. (Note: Adapter here basically is where API calling and mapping is done)

What I tried?

1. If-else block conditions with numeric 0-1 and >=2 values, separate rendering for both. But progress indicator is not rendering.

Code for your reference:

```
class LeadView extends StatefulWidget {

const LeadView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LeadView> createState() => _LeadViewState();
}

class _LeadViewState extends State<LeadView> {
  List<Lead> leads = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Future<void> fetchLeads() async {
    List<Lead> fetchedLeads = await LeadAdapter().fetchLeads();
    setState(() {
      leads = fetchedLeads;
      isLoading = false;
    });
    print('$leads');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchLeads();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      const CircularProgressIndicator();

      // User has reached the end of the list, fetch more data or perform any action
      // you want to do when scrolling reaches the bottom.
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const LeadsAppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: leads.length + 1, // +1 for the progress indicator
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print('Item Count --- ${leads.length + 1}');
          print('Index --- $index');
          if (index <= 1) {
            // Show first two list tiles - 0,1
            return Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.02),
                    child: Container(
                        // Rest of your code for the first list tile
                        // ...
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.04),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: const Color(0xffbbbbbb),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          boxShadow: const [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color(0x3f000000),
                              blurRadius: 4,
                              offset: Offset(0, 4),
                            ),
                          ],
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                            subtitle: Table(columnWidths: {
                          0: FractionColumnWidth(0.45),
                        }, children: [
                          // TableRows here

                          TableRow(
                            children: [
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Company: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  leads[index].ownerName,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(67, 67, 67, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TableRow(
                            children: [
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Domain Name: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  leads[index].website ?? '',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TableRow(
                            children: [
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Phone: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  leads[index].phone ?? '',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TableRow(
                            children: [
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Email: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  leads[index].email ?? '',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TableRow(
                            children: [
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Address1: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TableCell(
                                child: Text(
                                  leads[index].address ?? '',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ])))),
                if (isLoading) // Show progress indicator
                  const CustomProgressIndicator(),
              ],
            );
          } else if (index == leads.length && isLoading) {
            // Show the last item as a progress indicator
            return const CustomProgressIndicator();
          }  else {
            // Show remaining list tiles after the first two
            final leadIndex = index + 1;
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.02),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  CustomProgressIndicator(),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.02),
                      child: Container(

                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.04),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xffbbbbbb),
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            boxShadow: const [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Color(0x3f000000),
                                blurRadius: 4,
                                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                              ),
                            ],
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                              subtitle: Table(columnWidths: {
                                0: FractionColumnWidth(0.45),
                              }, children: [
                                // TableRows here

                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Company: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        leads[leadIndex].ownerName,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(67, 67, 67, 1),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Domain Name: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        leads[leadIndex].website ?? '',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Phone: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        leads[leadIndex].phone ?? '',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Email: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        leads[leadIndex].email ?? '',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Address1: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TableCell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        leads[leadIndex].address ?? '',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ])))),
                  if (isLoading) // Show progress indicator
                    const CustomProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              )
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called ***lazy loading*** in Flutter. It's ***very easy to achieve*** using this package [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination).

Here, I am sharing some of the code snippets that should be useful to you.

 **ui.dart file**

```
 PagedListView<int, CallBackModel>(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  pagingController: Get.put(
    CallBackController(),
  ).callbackPagingController,
  builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<CallBackModel>(
    noItemsFoundIndicatorBuilder: (_) => const Center(
      child: Text('No callbacks found'),
    ),
    newPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (_) =>
        AppWidget.circularProgressIndicator(),
    firstPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (_) =>
        AppWidget.circularProgressIndicator(),
    itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
      // Build your call log item UI here
      return ListTile();
    },
  ),
),
```

**contorller.dart file**

```
PagingController<int, CallBackModel> callbackPagingController =
      PagingController(
    firstPageKey: 1,
  );

  @override
  void onInit() {
    initFetchCallBack();
    super.onInit();
  }

  initFetchCallBack() {
    callbackPagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      fetchCallBacks(pageKey);
    });
  }

  refreshCallBacks() {
    callbackPagingController.refresh();
  }

  Future<void> fetchCallBacks(int pageKey) async {
    final apiResponse = await CallBackRepository.instance.getCallBack(
      page: pageKey,
      contactNumber: Get.arguments,
    );
    var isLastPage = (apiResponse.data).length < 10;

    if (isLastPage) {
      callbackPagingController.appendLastPage(apiResponse.data);
    } else {
      final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
      callbackPagingController.appendPage(apiResponse.data, nextPageKey);
    }
  }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. But if l am not wrong, this package is used to show the same thing scrolling infinitely. I want to break the api response in chunks and show one chunk after another whenever user scrolls